# Windows 11 tries to install Office 2010 when I open Word, Excel or Powerpoint

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

I have long since uninstalled Office 2010 from my Windows 11 computer, I have uninstalled it using standard Windows uninstall and even used a third-party tool like IOBit Uninstaller but the icon in Windows explorer for file types (doc/x, xls/x, ppt/x) are still using the icons of Office 2010, and when I try to click such files it install Office 2010 again:

[image]

In what way it can be totally removed from

- Windows explorer association (though the system settings App > Default Apps does not show any association)
- Windows Registry
- Other System components so it won't "try" to install it again.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the Bulk Crap Uninstaller [https://www.bcuninstaller.com/]

[image]

It seems that Office 2010 is a system component and I was able to uninstall it using BCU.

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall Office 2010, we can also run this script: OffScrub10.vbs

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-IT-Pro-Deployment-Scripts/blob/master/Office-ProPlus-Deployment/Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls/OffScrub10.vbs